# Trying to setup MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I feel like I am hitting my head against a wall... I started programming in May and know the very basics of web development thanks to a course from Angela Yu on Udemy.

I am trying to use MongoDB for a database for my apps, and I cannot for the life of me get it to function correctly, mostly because the course I am following is using 4.0 and the current version is 7.0 and there are, obviously, major differences.

So I was in a spot where I had to teach myself how to use MongoDB using the documentation... I was able to create collections within a database using native modules within NodeJS using the following code:

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
// Replace the uri string with your MongoDB deployment's connection string.
const uri = "mongodb+srv://pauldavew:****@cluster0.sr3ixob.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
async function run() {
  try {
    const database = client.db("insertDB");
    const foods = database.collection("foods");
    // create an array of documents to insert
    const docs = [
      { name: "cake", healthy: false },
      { name: "lettuce", healthy: true },
      { name: "donut", healthy: false }
    ];
    // this option prevents additional documents from being inserted if one fails
    const options = { ordered: true };
    const result = await foods.insertMany(docs, options);
    console.log(`${result.insertedCount} documents were inserted`);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

I was also able to find these collections and I used mongodb compass to view these collections.

I was never able to create collections on server 27017, I was only able to create them on the uri noted above, which I generated through mongodb's "connect with clusters" feature.

I guess my first question is how to create clusters and databases on the 27017 server.  If I use the above code and instead of using the link seen their  use the link: mongodb://localhost:27017 or any variation of it, then it will not work and as I mentioned, I have been unable to create anything on my 27017 server. (images below of error messages when using 27017)

Well I moved past this issue figuring I could just use the uri in the above code, and went to use mongoose, and I have been unable to use that in any way shape or form.  I cannot create anything on any url, either the one noted in my above code or on 27017.  I have spent hours going through the docs and stack overflow as well as consulting my course information and I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me figure out why I cannot use my 27017 port?
[image showing message when I enter mongod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kuo1D.png)

[Image of error message when I try to run above code using const uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017";](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwTv2.png)\

Here is the code I used to try to use mongoose:

```
//require the Mongoose package (after running >npm i mongoose in Hyper to install it)
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 
//connect to MongoDB by specifying port to access MongoDB server
main().catch(err => console.log(err));
 
async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://pauldavew:1234@cluster0.sr3ixob.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority');
  }
 
//create a SCHEMA that sets out the fields each document will have and their datatypes
const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    review: String
})
 
//create a MODEL
const Fruit = new mongoose.model ("Fruit", fruitSchema)
 
//create a DOCUMENT
const fruit = new Fruit ({
    name: "Apple",
    rating: 7,
    review: "Great!"
})
 
//save the document
fruit.save()
```

But the console would just sit there, until I pressed control c to quit.  It never gave me an error nor gave me an indication that it was working. When I looked for the files in compass I was unable to find them.

In summary I have two questions: why can't I insert anything onto the 27017 server, and why can't I use mongoose in any way shape or form?

Help me obi wan...

I tried everything I could at this point.